# Raspberry pi 4 is not booting with Disk image that is working on Raspberry pi2

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, pi-2, python-3, raspberry-pi-os

I am new to this project. The project was developed in 2015 using Raspberry pi2 and a 7' touch display. The disk image works perfectly on Raspberry pi 2. I tried to flash the disk image to an SD card and load it to the latest raspberry pi4. But It is not showing anything on the display. If I load Rasbian OS to the pi4, it works.

Are there any changes or updates needed when we switch to the latest version? The programs are all done using Kivy I guess(Python).

Comment: I think the Pi4 had an update to the boot process with new files required in `/boot`.  These would not be present on your old Pi2 image.  Have a search for updated Pi4 boot files.

Comment: The disk image we have is a compiled version. Is there any way to load old image and new OS together?

Comment: What do you mean by "compiled version", referring to the disk image?

Comment: This file if i flash on any sd card, will work in raspberry pi2, but it is not working in raspberry pi4

Answer (score 1):

The Pi4 was released on [24 Jun 2019](https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/raspberry-pi-4-on-sale-now-from-35/) and requires Buster.
The only (reliable) way of upgrading is to perform a fresh installation.

You will then have to reinstall applications you use.

If you have a compiled program it may work, but this depends on what resources it uses. One thing for certain don't use a 64bit OS - which is almost guaranteed to fail. If I were doing this I would avoid Bullseye and use "Legacy" i.e.  Buster.